# environment mode not working

Tags: tikz-feynman

Two problems I am facing. Its not numbering and title is not showing up.
Please help.thank you.

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Field Strength Renormalization}

\begin{equation}
\[
\langle \Omega \rangle
=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {\(x\)};
\vertex [right=of a] (b){\(y\)};

\diagram* {
(b)--[fermion](a)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {\(x\)};
\vertex [right=.5cm of a] (b);
\vertex [right=.5 cm of b] (c);
\vertex [right=.5 cm of c] (d){\(y\)};
\diagram* {
(a)--(c)--[fermion](b),(c)--(d),
(b)--[boson,out=135,in=45,looseness=5.0](c)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\cdot \cdot \cdot
\]
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: i am sorry.i forget how to write in a clean format..:(

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please make this into a full minimal example and not just a sniplet, then others can copy and test your example as is without having to add or guess anything. This makes it a lot easier to help

Comment: Off-topic but why are you choose the title "field strength renormalization" rather than "wave function renormalization" here?

Comment: oh.i am just writing summary of peskin qft.he wrote it that way..:D

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using `\[...\]` inside `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`. You need to drop either of these. Since I don't think equation numbers make too much sense in presentations, I dropped the latter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Field Strength Renormalization}

\[
\langle \Omega \rangle
=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {\(x\)};
\vertex [right=of a] (b){\(y\)};
\diagram* {
(b)--[fermion](a)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {\(x\)};
\vertex [right=.5cm of a] (b);
\vertex [right=.5 cm of b] (c);
\vertex [right=.5 cm of c] (d){\(y\)};
\diagram* {
(a)--(c)--[fermion](b),(c)--(d),
(b)--[boson,out=135,in=45,looseness=5.0](c)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\cdots
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]